# Understand memtest86+ memory mapping

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, x86

I'm trying to understand how memtest86+ works, however I don't understand a mapping operation. memtest86+ runs in 32 bit mode, and uses PAE to handle more than 4Gb. Still I don't fully understand how PAE works. At some point in initialization, it gets the e820 memory map from BIOS, the addresses are 64 bit integers (to be able to handle more than 4Gb?). Then it translates it to pages, dividing those addresses by 4k and stores it in 32 bit integer. After, I understand that it converts it back to "byte address" by doing these mapping operations:

```
void *mapping(unsigned long page_addr)
{
    void *result;
    if (page_addr < 0x80000) {
        /* If the address is less than 1GB directly use the address */
        result = (void *)(page_addr << 12);
    }
    else {
        unsigned long alias;
        alias = page_addr & 0x7FFFF;
        alias += 0x80000;
        result = (void *)(alias << 12);
    }
    return result;
}

void *emapping(unsigned long page_addr)
{
    void *result;
    result = mapping(page_addr -1);
    /* Fill in the low address bits */
    result = ((unsigned char *)result) + 0xffc;
    return result;
}
```

If the page is less than 0x80000 it just multiply it by 4k. But if not, how do those operations perform the mapping?

Thanks.